# Why my "onclick()" event doesn't work in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, events, onclick, components

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-popup playerOne" id="myForm_input" dir="rtl">
    <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">  
      <label for="funcs"><b>انتخاب ورودی</b></label>

      <mat-select placeholder="انتخاب ورودی" >
          <mat-option *ngFor="let input of inputs" [value]="input">
            {{ input }}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn " style="margin-top: 270px;" onclick="setInput($event)">اعمال</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">انصراف</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my component.ts code:

```
  setInput(event){
    console.log('the selected input is:' , event);
  }
```

But it seems it doesn't work because I don't see any log message on the console.

EDIT:

I changed my code like the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-popup playerOne" id="myForm_input" dir="rtl">
    <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">  
      <label for="funcs"><b>انتخاب ورودی</b></label>

      <mat-select placeholder="انتخاب ورودی" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValue">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let input of inputs" [value]="input">
            {{ input }}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn " style="margin-top: 270px;" (click)="setInput(selectedValue)">اعمال</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">انصراف</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  selectedValue: any;
  setInput(){
    console.log('the selected input is:' , this.selectedValue);
  }
```

But I get this error message:

```
FlowComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    at Function.missingNameException (forms.js:5421)
    at NgModel._checkName (forms.js:5928)
    at NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.js:5905)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:27784)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:38472)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:38411)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:39433)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:39376)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FlowComponent.html:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html

```
<button
  type="submit"
  class="btn"
  style="margin-top: 270px;"
  (click)="setInput()">اعمال</button>
```

In your component use

```
setInput(){
  console.log('the selected input is:' , this.selectedValue);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks but it says: Property 'selectedValue' does not exist on type 'FlowComponent'.

Comment: In your html add [(ngModel)] = "selectedValue" to mat-select. In your component declare selectedValue: any;

Comment: Add a name to mat-select

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the event binding syntax to make it work.

```
<button
  type="submit"
  class="btn"
  style="margin-top: 270px;"
  (click)="setInput($event)">اعمال</button>
```

Link to [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events)

Comment: I changed the code but still it seems it doesn't work!

Comment: Maybe I must pass another argument instead of `$event`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `(click)="setInput($event)"` as binding instead of `onclick="setInput($event)"`

Comment: I changed the code but still it seems it doesn't work!

Comment: Maybe I must pass another argument instead of $event?

Answer (score 1):

you should add template variable to pass the data into function. for that use ngModel and pass this ngModel variable as input for (click)

```
     <mat-select placeholder="انتخاب ورودی" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValue">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let input of inputs" [value]="input">
                 {{ input }}
               </mat-option>
           </mat-select>

             <button type="submit" class="btn " style="margin-top: 270px;"                   (click)="setInput(selectedValue)">اعمال</button>
```

Comment: I modified the code like what you said and also modified this part like `  setInput(selectedValue){
    console.log('the selected input is:' , selectedValue);
  }
` but still doen't work!

Comment: console.log(this.selectedValue)